# libapache2-mod-passenger update breaks redmine

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, redmine

After a security update on a ubuntu 12.04 server redmine 2.5 is broken (error 500). we recoginized that libapache2-mod-passenger was updated from

```
libapache2-mod-passenger=2.2.11debian-2
```

to

```
libapache2-mod-passenger=2.2.11debian-2+deb6u1ubuntu12.04.1
```

Downgrading this package again solved the problem. What can I do to not run into same problem with next security update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding Packages

Holding a package basically means you're telling the package manager to keep the current version no matter what. This is useful if more recent version of a currently working program breaks after an update.

```
sudo apt-mark hold libapache2-mod-passenger
```

For additional information [PinningHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)

Comment: Instead of advising people to withhold security updates (which is an incredibly dangerous advise), a much better advise would be to find out what exactly broke and to fix this instead.